# Magento2 override register.phtml in custom theme

Tags: magento2

Magento2 override register.phtml file in following path

```
app/design/frontend/xyz/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form
```

I did  this but some how un successful, + if I override customer_account_create.xml file then google recaptche is not working

Please guide me

Comment: Please refer below Url https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/override-form-register-phtml-template-in-magento-2/ https://www.hiddentechies.com/blog/magento-2/magento-2-override-registration-page-template/ it's helpful for you.

Comment: you have to check register.phtml file is overridden on other modules.

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1 In Theme**

override `register.phtml` in your theme on below path.

app/design/frontend/your/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

---

**Way 2 In Module**

Create a XML file

`app/code/<Vendor>/<Modulename>/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @author  Rakesh Jesadiya
 * @package Rbj_Modulename
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Modulename::form/register.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Note: Vendor => BG, Modulename =>Customregister